# Mejora para Interface de stored con Dapper

Tags: c#, revisión-de-código, orm, arquitectura

estoy escribiendo una propuesta para reemplezar la capa de acceso a datos de la empresa donde trabajo, para esto estoy usando una interfaz generica para ejecutar procedimientos almacenados usando Dapper ORM.

Mi pregunta es como podria mejorar el codigo?

Este es la interfaz:

```
public interface IStored
    {
        int Execute(string Name);
        int Execute<Output>(string Name, Output Parameters) where Output : class;

        IEnumerable<Output> Execute<Output>(string Name) where Output : class;
        IEnumerable<Output> Execute<Input, Output>(string Name, Input Parameters)
            where Output : class
            where Input : class;
    }
```

Y esta es la implementacion de la interfaz:

```
public class Stored : DataBaseContext, IStored
    {
        public Stored() : base() { }

        public int Execute(string Name)
        {
            try
            {
                Connection.Open();
                var result = Connection.Execute(Name, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                Connection.Close();

                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    Connection.Close();
                return -1;
            }
        }

        public int Execute<T>(string Name, T Parameters) where T : class
        {
            try
            {
                Connection.Open();
                var result = Connection.Execute(Name, Parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                Connection.Close();

                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    Connection.Close();
                return -1;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<Output> Execute<Output>(string Name) where Output : class
        {
            try
            {
                Connection.Open();
                var result = Connection.Query<Output>(Name, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                Connection.Close();

                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    Connection.Close();

                return null;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<Output> Execute<Input, Output>(string Name, Input Parameters)
            where Output : class
            where Input : class
        {
            try
            {
                Connection.Open();
                var result = Connection.Query<Output>(Name, Parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                Connection.Close();

                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    Connection.Close();

                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

La clase stored hereda de al clase DataBaseContext que es la encargada de obtener la conexion en el web.config

Comment: Hola! tu pregunta es bastante amplia a mi parecer,  podrías ser mas concreto/a  en cuanto a que te gustaría mejorar? desde ya que es una pregunta interesante, pero generalmente las preguntas demasiado amplias o que se basen en opiniones se votan para ser cerradas. Abrazo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Porque Dapper y no Entity Framework

[Code First Insert/Update/Delete Stored Procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn468673.aspx)

con este podrias mapear procedure a entidades y ademas si quieres puedes alguna entidad dejar que el propio ORM sea quien genere las queries.

Lo que si no recomendaria que generes una clase como la de `Stored`, sino que deberias implementar el patron `Repository`

[[Entity Framework][Code First] Crear entidad simple](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2013/06/entity-frameworkcode-first-crear.html)

Entonces puedes generar un `RepositoryBase` con funcionalidad comun, pero que tambien puedes extender, pero el diseño se realiza segun la entidad que represeta de tu modelo de negocio.

Comment: Hola, la razón por la que no estoy implementando el patrón repositorio es por que toda la logica se encuentra en stored procedures, ademas Entity ejecutando stored procedures es un poco mas lento. Sin duda tener un repositorio ahorra una buena cantidad de código pero la especificacion del cliente es usar specs

Comment: ok pero que la logica la tengas en el procedure no quiere decir que puedas definir entidades de dominio como ser Cliente, Articulo, Factura,etc y generar repositorios para estos con la funcionalidad que exponen los procedure. Mas alla que implementes Dapper creo que aplicar un patron que permite inyectar funcionalidad segun las entidades de negocio es mas util que generar una clase generica "Stored" y usarla en cualquier lado, mas que nada por un tema de mantenibilidad del codigo

Comment: Entonces, podemos decir que si un procedure ejecuta una accion de actualizar o insertar puede caer dentro de la acción correspondiente al Repositorio. ¿Esa sería la manera mas correcta para mantener el código mantenible?